# Who produced all-in-one / wedge style IBM compatibles?

Tags: ibm-pc, sinclair, tandy-1000, amstrad

The [RetroManCave YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLEoyoOKZK0idGqSc6Pi23w) recently made me aware of the Sinclair PC-200 / Amstrad PC-20 and I already knew about the Tandy 1000EX / 1000HX but were there any other IBM-compatibles (or mostly compatible) using that same all-in-one wedge form factor?

Comment: This one is about as wedgy as can be, but unfortunately not "retro": https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/B07Y1TPKYY/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&dchild=1&keywords=pipo+x8&qid=1602337688&sr=8-1

Comment: Haha yes, not entirely what I had in mind (reminds me of those Logitech Tap / Rooms thingies) but thanks all the same!

Comment: Joking by side, there is a new(ish) ARM based keyboard/machine available from a company in Florida. I just can't  remember the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three jump direct to mind:

- [Schneider Euro-PC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneider_Euro_PC) and Euro-PC II
- [Amstrad PPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPC_512)
- Vendex Headstart Explorer
- [Laser Compact XT](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vtech-laser-compact-xt-original-box-1870114433) by VTech ([thanks mnem](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/who-produced-all-in-one-wedge-style-ibm-compatibles/16504#comment55669_16504))

Not to mention the [WEB-IT](https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/C64_Web.it), a 486 based as an all in one unit, introduced as late as 1998.

Comment: With its built-in screen, the PPC wasn't really wedge-shaped, was it?

Comment: Well, while offering more then the EuroPC, I would still put it into the same category. A all in one unit with attached keyboard, which is the most relevant feature of this computer class, isn't it?

Comment: Also the Laser Compact XT by VTech, nearly identical form factor to their earlier Laser 128 Apple II clone.

Comment: I was going to suggest the Amstrad PPC myself, as my parents used to have one.  It could be used as a primitive laptop as it had a built-in LCD, but could also be attached to an external CGA monitor.

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses and some really interesting computers to read up on!

Comment: The PPC and PC20/PC200 are very similar computers, both using the same chipset. The main difference is that where the PPC has a built-in LCD screen, the PC20/PC200 has TV output.

Answer (score 4):

There was the [Schneider Euro PC](http://www.classiccomputer.de/ams/scheuropc.htm). Schneider had been selling Amstrad computers (the CPC line, the PC 1512/1640, and the Joyce) in Germany. The Euro PC in 1989 was their first attempt at an own design, doubtless inspired by the success of the Amiga 500 and the Atari 520/1040 ST.

Answer (score 3):

I had (though have since sold) a Key-Comp 386 similar to the one [pictured](https://atariage.com/forums/topic/269326-were-there-any-other-computers-like-the-tandy-1000-exhx/?do=findComment&comment=3860723) at atariage.com. It had two ISA slots (for video and network cards) at the left-hand end of the case, and built-in parallel and serial ports.

Comment: This is very cool! Would quite like to get my hands on one.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably from after the timeframe you were thinking of, but a company called Cybernet (which still exists) used to make "Zero Footprint PCs" in which the entire computer (sans display but usually including disk drives) was contained within the keyboard.

Comment: Might be cool if you could add some link and possible a picture as that seems to be a quite unknown one.